# First Come First Serve (FCFS) CPU Scheduling in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to create fcfs that accepts 5 jobs in C#. I need help with what formula to use to calculate waiting time and turn around time. Also, i am planning to display the output on the Convert.ToString() part. How should i implement this one? Thanks.

```
private void btnFCFS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtAT1.Text); a2 = Convert.ToInt32(txtAT2.Text); a3 = Convert.ToInt32(txtAT3.Text); a4 = Convert.ToInt32(txtAT4.Text);
        a5 = Convert.ToInt32(txtAT5.Text); b1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtBT1.Text); b2 = Convert.ToInt32(txtBT2.Text); b3 = Convert.ToInt32(txtBT3.Text);
        b4 = Convert.ToInt32(txtBT4.Text); b5 = Convert.ToInt32(txtBT5.Text);


        int[][] arrayprocess = new int[][] { new int[] { a1, b1 }, new int[] { a2, b2 }, new int[] { a3, b3 }, new int[] { a4, b4 }, new int[] { a5, b5 } };

        Sort<int>(arrayprocess, 0);

        label8.Text = Convert.ToString(arrayprocess[0][0] + " " + arrayprocess[1][0] + " " +arrayprocess[2][0] + " " +arrayprocess[3][0] + " " +arrayprocess[4][0]);
        label9.Text = Convert.ToString(arrayprocess[0][1] + " " + arrayprocess[1][1] + " " + arrayprocess[2][1] + " " + arrayprocess[3][1] + " " + arrayprocess[4][1]);
        int totalburst = arrayprocess[0][1] + arrayprocess[1][1] +  arrayprocess[2][1] +  arrayprocess[3][1] + arrayprocess[4][1];
        label10.Text = Convert.ToString(totalburst);

        //Gantt Chart
        Graphics dc = this.CreateGraphics();
        Pen Bluepen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 3);
        dc.DrawRectangle(Bluepen, 50, 200, arrayprocess[0][1] *10, 20);
        Pen Redpen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);
        dc.DrawRectangle(Redpen, 50 + arrayprocess[0][1] * 10, 200, arrayprocess[1][1] * 10, 20);
        Pen Yellowpen = new Pen(Color.Yellow, 3);
        dc.DrawRectangle(Yellowpen, 50 + arrayprocess[0][1] *10 + arrayprocess[1][1] * 10, 200, arrayprocess[2][1] * 10, 20);
        Pen Greenpen = new Pen(Color.Green, 3);
        dc.DrawRectangle(Greenpen, 50 + (arrayprocess[0][1] + arrayprocess[1][1] + arrayprocess[2][1]) * 10, 200, arrayprocess[3][1] * 10, 20);
        Pen Violetpen = new Pen(Color.Violet, 3);
        dc.DrawRectangle(Violetpen, 50 + (arrayprocess[0][1] + arrayprocess[1][1] + arrayprocess[2][1] + arrayprocess[3][1]) * 10, 200, arrayprocess[4][1] * 10, 20);

        lblWT1.Text = Convert.ToString();
        lblWT2.Text = Convert.ToString();
        lblWT3.Text = Convert.ToString();
        lblWT4.Text = Convert.ToString();
        lblWT5.Text = Convert.ToString();

        lblTAT1.Text = Convert.ToString();
        lblTAT2.Text = Convert.ToString();
        lblTAT3.Text = Convert.ToString();
        lblTAT4.Text = Convert.ToString();
        lblTAT5.Text = Convert.ToString();

    }

    public void Sort<T>(T[][] data, int col)
    {
        Comparer<T> comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
        Array.Sort<T[]>(data, (x, y) => comparer.Compare(x[col], y[col]));          
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace FCFS_2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           
        }
       
        private void btnFCFS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int  a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5;
            a1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtAT1.Text); a2 = Convert.ToInt32(txtAT2.Text); a3 = Convert.ToInt32(txtAT3.Text); a4 = Convert.ToInt32(txtAT4.Text);
            a5 = Convert.ToInt32(txtAT5.Text); b1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtBT1.Text); b2 = Convert.ToInt32(txtBT2.Text); b3 = Convert.ToInt32(txtBT3.Text);
            b4 = Convert.ToInt32(txtBT4.Text); b5 = Convert.ToInt32(txtBT5.Text);


            int[][] arrayprocess = new int[][] { new int[] { a1, b1 }, new int[] { a2, b2 }, new int[] { a3, b3 }, new int[] { a4, b4 }, new int[] { a5, b5 } };

            Sort<int>(arrayprocess, 0);

            label8.Text = Convert.ToString(arrayprocess[0][0] + " " + arrayprocess[1][0] + " " + arrayprocess[2][0] + " " + arrayprocess[3][0] + " " + arrayprocess[4][0]);
            label9.Text = Convert.ToString(arrayprocess[0][1] + " " + arrayprocess[1][1] + " " + arrayprocess[2][1] + " " + arrayprocess[3][1] + " " + arrayprocess[4][1]);
            int totalburst = arrayprocess[0][1] + arrayprocess[1][1] + arrayprocess[2][1] + arrayprocess[3][1] + arrayprocess[4][1];
            label10.Text = Convert.ToString(totalburst);

            //Gantt Chart
            Graphics dc = this.CreateGraphics();
            Pen Bluepen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 3);
            dc.DrawRectangle(Bluepen, 50, 200, arrayprocess[0][1] * 10, 20);
            Pen Redpen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);
            dc.DrawRectangle(Redpen, 50 + arrayprocess[0][1] * 10, 200, arrayprocess[1][1] * 10, 20);
            Pen Yellowpen = new Pen(Color.Yellow, 3);
            dc.DrawRectangle(Yellowpen, 50 + arrayprocess[0][1] * 10 + arrayprocess[1][1] * 10, 200, arrayprocess[2][1] * 10, 20);
            Pen Greenpen = new Pen(Color.Green, 3);
            dc.DrawRectangle(Greenpen, 50 + (arrayprocess[0][1] + arrayprocess[1][1] + arrayprocess[2][1]) * 10, 200, arrayprocess[3][1] * 10, 20);
            Pen Violetpen = new Pen(Color.Violet, 3);
            dc.DrawRectangle(Violetpen, 50 + (arrayprocess[0][1] + arrayprocess[1][1] + arrayprocess[2][1] + arrayprocess[3][1]) * 10, 200, arrayprocess[4][1] * 10, 20);

            lblWT1.Text = Convert.ToString(arrayprocess[0][0]);
            lblWT2.Text = Convert.ToString(arrayprocess[0][1]-arrayprocess[1][0]);
            lblWT3.Text = Convert.ToString(arrayprocess[0][1]+arrayprocess[1][1]-arrayprocess[2][0]);
            lblWT4.Text = Convert.ToString(arrayprocess[0][1]+arrayprocess[1][1]+arrayprocess[2][1]-arrayprocess[3][0]);
            lblWT5.Text = Convert.ToString(arrayprocess[0][1]+arrayprocess[1][1]+arrayprocess[2][1]+ arrayprocess[3][1] - arrayprocess[4][0]);

            lblTAT1.Text = Convert.ToString(arrayprocess[0][0]+arrayprocess[0][1]);
            lblTAT2.Text = Convert.ToString(arrayprocess[0][1]-arrayprocess[1][0]+arrayprocess[1][1]);
            lblTAT3.Text = Convert.ToString(arrayprocess[0][1]+arrayprocess[1][1]-arrayprocess[2][0]+arrayprocess[2][1]);
            lblTAT4.Text = Convert.ToString(arrayprocess[0][1]+arrayprocess[1][1]+arrayprocess[2][1]-arrayprocess[3][0]+arrayprocess[3][1]);
            lblTAT5.Text = Convert.ToString(arrayprocess[0][1]+arrayprocess[1][1]+arrayprocess[2][1]+ arrayprocess[3][1] - arrayprocess[4][0]+arrayprocess[4][1]);


        }
        public void Sort<T>(T[][] data, int col)
        {
            Comparer<T> comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
            Array.Sort<T[]>(data, (x, y) => comparer.Compare(x[col], y[col]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer would be much better if the proposed code has explanations about the changes you made and also focuses on those changes.